# Why can't I open a Nether or End in creative mode?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I would like to know why I can't open a Nether or End portal in creative mode. When I do it with the Nether portal, the obsidian just gets set on fire. When I try opening and End Portal, nothing happens. Does this have to do with the fact that I'm in creative mode,  or because I have done it wrong somehow?

Comment: add screenshots

Comment: Are you on a superflat world?

Comment: No, I'm in a regular world.

Comment: That's interesting... If possible, try to add screenshots. Also, have you tried doing this in 
survival mode or in a different world?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure your not doing it right because it need to be 4x5 for a nether portal, and 3x3x3x3 or 3 on each side facing to middle of the end portal

Comment: That's what I'm doing.